# Are there any API's available for music on google/youtube?

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api

If you search songs on google, you can sometimes get on [these pages](https://www.google.be/search?q=google%20artists&oq=google%20artists&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2101j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=walls%20of%20jericho%20the%20new%20ministry&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAGOovnz8BQMDgyEHsxCXfq6-QUpecUllvBKCbaYlmp1spZ9bWpyZrJ-Yk1Saa1Wcn5deHJ40NaNp1guB9ugoxcT3m74UX1lzHgDngTNwTgAAAA).
These pages contain information about albums, artists, songs and the corresponding YouTube url.

I was wondering if this information is also available in an API somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Play Music Action](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/actions/play-music) under the [Search API](https://developers.google.com/search/)